# preg_replace regular-expression to find numbers preceeded by letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm really confused as to using `preg_replace` but slowly learning.

I need help with the function:

```
$str= preg_replace('#\W\d+#', '\W \d+', $str);
```

The idea is that Im looking for numbers that have letters directly before them with no spaces,

ie **abc123**. (NOT 'abc 123' and NOT '123abc')

and how do I simply include a space or character in between so abc123 becomes abc 123 or abc@@123

thanks everyone!

Comment: Take a look here: http://txt2re.com/ it might help

Comment: thanks but Ive been coding too much tonight and looking at that makes my head hurt!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'abc()1234';
$str= preg_replace('#([a-zA-Z()])(\d+)#', '$1 $2', $str);

echo $str;
```

Output:

> abc() 1234

$1 and $2 are backreferences and refer to the first and second captured groups, respectively. More info @ http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html.

Comment: I used preg_match in my example so you can actually see how the array is populated and what you can use for preg_replace. $1 and $2 would reference the first and second captured pieces, per chaos's example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you help with my latest comment: 'very good, works a treat. But for me I might actually need to check for brackets before the numbers too, so can the pattern do abc()123 as well?'

Comment: Thanks so much, Im gonna give you the right answer but you were both spot on.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
$str= preg_replace('#([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)#', '$1 $2', $str);
```

`\W` doesn't do what you think it does; `\w` means "word character" and `\W` means "*not* word character".  Since you specifically want *letters*, though, neither does what you want, and you need `[A-Za-z]`, which is the character class matching all letters.  You also need a `+` after it in order to match "one or more".

Parentheses are how you "capture" part of the expression for later reference; `$1` and `$2` refer to your parenthesis-captured text.

Comment: very good, works a treat. But for me I might actually need to check for brackets before the numbers too, so can the pattern do abc()123 as well?

Comment: Make [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z()] and include any other characters inside, you may need to escape [ and ] if you do though.

Comment: Thanks man that worked really well. Can't tell you what a help youve been

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference between `/([A-Za-z])(\d+)/` and `/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/` in the [online PHP Regegular expressor tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm). Both work with preg_replace in your case. But the latter also works with preg_match_all, so it's more robust.